# Detecting vibration in voiced and voiceless English sounds

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

I heard people saying that if you put your finger on your throat you would be able to feel voiced sound vibrates and voiceless sound doesn't. I tried it but both sounds seem the same to me. So did I do wrong, and how to "feel" this correctly? Thanks

Comment: Which sounds did you try it with?

Comment: You should be able to feel your vocal cords vibrating without touching your throat.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to feel the difference between a voiced and unvoiced sound. You can put your hand on your throat (not a bad method); you can put the whole of the palm of your hand on the top of your head (a very good method); you can try sticking your finger in your ear -  or even one finger in each ear ( works very well for a lot of people).

Now, we want a good pair of sounds to contrast. Because we are just learning to tell the difference, we need a sound where it is easier to feel the vibration. To help us do this a) the sound needs to be a type of sound that we can make for a long time, b) it needs to be a sound where the vibration is felt strongly in the bone and other tissue in the head.

So short consonants such as the plosives /p, t, k, b, d, g/  are not a good choice here. Vowels aren't good because the vibration doesn't transmit to the facial tissue because the air escapes freely through the mouth. Nasals sounds such as /m, n, ŋ/ are usable, but they are not great. With these sounds we definitely can feel some vibration, but it's not very strong. These are sonorant sounds, and because the air leaves the *nose* freely the vibration doesn't transmit to the other tissue very well.

What we need is fricatives. These are sounds where we make a blockage in the mouth and then force air through a small hole in that blockage. These are the voiced fricative sounds in English:

- /v/ as in **v**ery
- /ð/ as in **th**e
- /z/ as in **z**oo
- /ʒ/ as in televi**s**ion

Now you need some good unvoiced sounds to compare with. Here are the unvoiced fricatives in English:

- /f/ as in **f**ine
- /θ/ as in **th**ink
- /s/ as in **s**top
- /ʃ/ as in **sh**ower

Now choose one of the sounds in the first group. Choose a sound you can make very well. If you're not a native speaker, choose a sound that is exactly the same in your first language and in English, if possible. Now, say that sound for a very long time, maybe five seconds. For example "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz". Put your hand on your head and try it; put your finger in your ear and try it; put your hand on  your throat and try it. Now, can your hum a tune using this sound? If you are  making the sound correctly, you should be able to do this. Now try with some of the other voiced sounds too. Hopefully you will be able to feel the vibration using one of these three methods.

Right, after you've done that try the exactly same thing with an unvoiced sound, maybe "sssssssssss", for example.  Experiment with the different methods for feeling the vibrations. This time you won't be able to feel any vibration. Also, if you are making the sound correctly, you won't be able to hum a tune with it. These sounds don't have any pitch. There is no musical note present. This pitch or musical tone comes directly from the vocal fold vibration.

Lastly, choose the most successful method you used for feeling the vibration. Switch between different sounds. The difference should become clearer to you now.

Comment: Nice explanation. Humming is a good trick. Also the opposite, whispering...'very' and 'fairy' are exactly the same when whispering.

Comment: If after all this someone still had trouble with /d/ and /dʒ/ etc, the singing trick works for them too: you could _chop_ a tune into separate blows of repeated /d/s (or /dʒ/s etc) and sing along, which is not possible with the /t/ sound for example.

Comment: @Farid That's a good trick, I'm going to steal that for my students, thanks!

Comment: I wish you wouldn't use slashes, which often indicate phonemic or underlying forms, when you are clearly not talking about phonemes at all.

Comment: @GregLee Here we go again. Us phoneticians use slanty brackets for broad transcription. This isn't a phonology post.

Comment: But it's not true.  I just looked up "brackets" in *A Course in Phonetics*, and on page 46 Ladefoged explains the difference between slashes and brackets, and on page 50 he uses brackets for broad transcription. Here is the reference: https://books.google.com/books?id=FjLc1XtqJUUC&q=brackets#v=snippet&q=brackets&f=false

Comment: @GregLee The way that Lagefoged is using *phonemic* there is misleading (as is the term *phonemic* in general when used by phoneticians). What he is talking about is using diacritics and other symbols that can be used to give allophonic or other narrow information about the production of the sound. In other words it is a narrow transcription. By *phonemic* phoneticians often mean just using the plain language-specific transcription symbosl and nothing more.

Comment: @GregLee Notice that on page 50 he is asking the reader which of two transciptions is a narrow transcription and which is broad. With that exercise in mind, why do you think he notes that he has used square brackets for both transcriptions?

Comment: Why does he note he uses brackets for broad transcription?  I have to guess.  Probably because he wants to be clear that phonetic transcriptions, narrow or broad, are phonetic.  That is to say, they describe facts of pronunciation.  Phonemic transcriptions are quite different.  They are theoretical.  The nature of phonemes is in dispute, but I would say, phonemic transcriptions describe facts of perception. At any rate, it is an important distinction to make, and it is often made, even by phoneticians.  There are plenty of phoneticians who know about phonemics. Believe me.

Comment: @GregLee No, it's because he could have used slanty brackets for the broad transcription - but that in itself would have told the reader that it was the broad transcription!!!

Comment: So he used brackets because they were unnecessary?  That doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @GregLee He could have used // for the broad one  and [] for the narrow one. However, using // would already indicate that that transcription was broad one, which would render the exercise redundant. Otherwise he wouldn't have bothered to comment on the brackets in the first place: why would he?

Comment: You are just totally missing what I'm trying to tell you about the difference between phonetics and phonemics.

Comment: @GregLee Why does he make the brackets comment: **"For this exercise both transcriptions have been put between square brackets"** ?

Comment: I refer you to my previous answer.  I could add: because he knows that some readers of his book don't know anything about phonemics.  Like you.

Comment: So he does a few hundred exercises with no such comments, but then he adds that comment specially for this particular one along with the preposition phrase "For THIS exercise ...".

Comment: Is that really true, that the difference broad and narrow came up previously in those hundreds of exercises, yet he made no special note?  I don't know.  I always thought the reason for broad transcriptions was expedience or sloppiness.  But who cares?  The point here is they are phonetic and not phonemic.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, I think, is that the supposedly voiced sounds you have trouble with are not actually voiced.  Just because they are *classified* as voiced, it doesn't mean the voiced obstruent phonemes of English are always actually voiced.  According to **The Sound Pattern of English**, which is a standard reference for phonetic features, obstruents by definition have a tendency to be voiceless -- there is an obstruction in the vocal tract sufficient to prevent spontaneous voicing because of the air pressure that develops behind the obstruction and slows the air passing up through the glottis.  To produce voice, the vocal cords have to have considerable air passing through, which pulls them together and blows them apart, periodically.

The obstruents are the non-nasal stops and the fricatives.  Unless some special measures are taken to maintain the air speed past the vocal cords, the air speed will be slowed down so much that the vibration of the vocal cords ceases, and there is no voicing.  There are several measures that can be taken to keep air flowing and maintain voicing for obstruents: loosen the cheeks to let them bulge out, lower the jaw to create more volume in the mouth, pull the glottis down (which can produce implosive sounds).

But the bottom line is that often obstruents will be devoiced.  In English, at the end of a word, and when there is no following voiced sound, b d g are often voiceless.  Even in a phonetic transcription, they are generally still written down as if they were voiced, but don't be fooled.  There may be no actual vocal cord vibration, so if you don't hear the voice, that may very well be because it is not there.

Comment: This will often be true when you say the sounds in connected speech. It may be true for stops when pronounced in isolation, but it won't be true if you isolate a fricative sound. It's true within words and in connected speech if the obstruents aren't surrounded by voiced sounds. But if you look at a waveform for an intervocalic fricative you will often clearly be able to see voicing all the way through  ... For example if you look at the waveform recorded for the /z/s in ["news item" here](http://swphonetics.com/praat/tutorials/understanding-waveforms/speech-waveforms/) ...

Comment: ... The first, intervocalic one seems to have clear voicing wheres the second is devoiced where it occurs next to silence.

Comment: @Araucaria, yes, I agree with all that.